# Core Data objects sometimes not saved to permanent store

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, save

I have a strange problem with Core Data in an complex app. The functionality can be described best like a shopping cart. The user puts items in this cart, can pay them, and so on. At the beginning everything works fine. The objects are all saved to the sqlite file. But then after some time, suddenly (mostly but not always after a restart of the app) some of the data is missing. Some new shopping carts are gone, and old ones, which had been completely processed, are open again (so their status update has not been saved).

Some of my saving operations take a few seconds, so I do them in background, while the user can go on. The only thing I can imagine is, that these saving operations get queued up and on restart are deleted out of the memory without getting written to the permanent store.

I tried things like the following, but with no success:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [self saveContext];
}

- (void)saveContext {
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (managedObjectContext != nil) {
        if ([managedObjectContext hasChanges] && ![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            abort();
        }
    }
}
```

My background savings are done with:

```
[managedObjectContext performBlock:^{
    [managedObjectContext save:nil];
    [managedObjectContext.parentContext performBlock:^{
        [managedObjectContext.parentContext save:nil];
    }];
}];
```

Comment: First step when you have a problem with saving is passing in an error parameter in your `save:` method and find out whether it gets populated or not.

Comment: Thank you, you are absolutely right. Now I implemented the background solution below and inserted the error parameter back in every saving.

Answer (score 0):

probably your save in background is terminated by the system.

`Your implementation of this method has approximately five seconds to perform 
any tasks and return. If you need additional time to perform any final tasks, 
you can request additional execution time from the system by calling
beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:. In practice, you should return from
applicationDidEnterBackground: as quickly as possible. If the method does not 
return before time runs out your app is terminated and purged from memory.`

from [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiapplicationdelegate_protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/applicationDidEnterBackground:)

Comment: So i can put my `[self saveContext]` into `bgTask = [[UIApplication  sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:`?

Comment: read this: [Background Execution](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html)

Comment: Thank you, i will give this implementation a try.